# Link Android project to Dropbox get Error?

Tags: android, dropbox

I am using Android 2.1 platform.On my first project [ say **Contacts** ],I am trying to get all the contacts from the emulator.This work is completed using the Eclipse and AVD.On next project [ say **AppBox** ],I did Authenticate to the DropBox.

On the same project I used the DropBoxUtility.java class.Now I can create the files and folders on my DropBox folder using this project. But I cant able to merge the Contacts project and AppBox projects to a single project.I am using the CONTACT_URI to get all the contacts, the error I got when I merging was on this line

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
```

**Error is "The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type DropBoxUtility"**

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

try using `getApplicationContext()` as:

```
ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver() ;
```

Comment: After replacing the code the error changed to " The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type DropBoxUtility "

Comment: then use Application class for getting Context in  DropBoxUtility class